# Cannot retrieve data from ajax with request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, post

I'm having problems retrieving data from an ajax post in an easy aplication, just making some tests.

I'm working with something easy:

I have 2 classes:

Controller.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/urlpost", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST} )
public urlPostTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

      String name  = request.getParameter("post_name");
      String age = request.getParameter("post_age");
      System.out.println("His name is: " + name);
      System.out.println("His age is: " + age);
}
```

And

PostingClass.js

```
function posting(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'urlpost',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        'post_name': "Peter",
        'post_age': "22"
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
        console.log("Send data: SUCCES.");
    }
});

}
```

The ajax goes correctly to the url, but the request is always null.

What could be the problem?.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that first line `HttpServletRequest request;`? Did u try removing it?

Comment: sorry my fault, that line shouldnt be there. edited.

Comment: what framework are you using to create the web application?

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getParameter("post_name"); // works on application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

To get the data from a application/json request, use something like this:

```
String jsonStr = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
String name = getString("name");
```